# HttpClient disposed before response stream fully read, leads to connection closed exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to stream the response of a request to the response. So basically pipe through the request to another url. This is the code I have, which illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetArticleImage(string userId, string articleId)
{
    var imageUrl = "https://image-url"; // This url is retrieved from the database
    var imageResult = await this.httpClient.GetAsync(imageUrl);
    var stream = await imageResult.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, imageResult.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").First());
}
```

What happens in this case is that a `ConnectionResetException` is thrown, with the message `The client has disconnected`.

I believe this happens because the request scope is disposed before the stream is fully read, which also disposes the `HttpClient`.
When a custom scope is created using `var scope = IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope()` (pseudo code, actually an `IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory` is injected via the constructor), the `HttpClient` resolved via that one, *and not disposed* (neither scope nor client), it works without issue.

What is important to mention is that the method `GetArticleImage` is implemented in a separate service class, *not* in a controller.
Previously it was implemented in a controller class, where the code worked flawlessly.
This leads me to the assumption that the scope dispose mechanism works somehow slightly differently, but I didn't find out how.

The `HttpClient` is registered as singleton, which should make sure it's not disposed of.

**The question is: How can a request be piped/streamed to another url?**

The endpoint that calls this method can be called quite often, with many simultaneous requests, so I'd like to avoid having to cache the response in memory only to pass it along.

Comment: Have you tired to call `LoadIntoBufferAsync` before calling `ReadAsStreamAsync`? [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.loadintobufferasync)

Comment: How did you register your HttpClient? in this way? services.AddSingleton<System.Net.Http.HttpClient>(); you'd better register httpclient using services.AddHttpClient(); and in your service, Inject IHttpClientFactory, and call HttpClientFactory.CreateClient to create httpclient

Comment: refer to this document for more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: and there is another document that your can refer to that why you should not directly new a httpclient https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens when external service works incorrect with .Net async/await

I found workaround(which is not best practice) But it worked for me.

```
public Task<IActionResult> GetArticleImage(string userId, string articleId)
{
    var imageUrl = "https://image-url"; // This url is retrieved from the database
    var imageResult = this.httpClient.GetAsync(imageUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var stream = imageResult.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, imageResult.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").First());
}
```